# Parameterised Bulid Step Command in Jenkins

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, rpa, blueprism

I have a requirement to run a Blue Prism process on a Slave VM using Jenkins. This process will take inputs from the command line. The data for these inputs will come from a CSV file inside the Master VM.

1. Jenkins job to get CSV columns and store them into variables (Master VM)

   ```
    @echo off
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set InputFile= <CSV file path here>
    for /f "skip=1 tokens=1-4 delims=," %%A in ('type "%InputFile%"') do (
      set SCENARIO=%%A
      set CREATED_BY=%%B
      set CTN=%%C
      set REGDATE=%%D
   ```
2. Jenkins build command to run the required Blue Prism process on Slave VM through Master VM:

   ```
    AutomateC.exe /run <Process Name> /sso /resource <Slave VM Name> /port <Port Name> /startp` "<inputs>`<input name = "creator" type = 'text' value = <Value from CREATED_BY here in quotes> /><input name = "ctn" type = 'text' value = <Value from CTN here in quotes> /><input name = "regdate" type = 'text' value = <Value from REGDATE here in quotes> /></inputs>"
   ```

Is there a way through with data flow can be created between these two Jenkins jobs? This will help me in keeping the 2nd command parametrized depending upon the change in values in CSV File.

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear about what the problem you're running into is? My apologies, as my expertise is more on the Blue Prism side, but can't you concatenate the extracted variables into the Jenkins build command (#2)?

Comment: @esqew I want to parametrize my inputs in AutomateC command when triggering via Jenkins. My requirement is to automatically get these inputs from a csv file. Is there any way to do it?